# Using WHERE in query PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to create a program where a user can enter an operator i.e. <> or = and then a number for a database in pymysql. I have tried a number of different ways of doing this but unfortunately unsuccessful. I have two documents with display being one and importing display into the other document.

Docuemnt 1

```
def get_pop(op, pop):
if (not conn):
    connect();

query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE Population %s %s"


with conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, (op, pop))
    x = cursor.fetchall()
    return x
```

Document two

```
 def city():
     op = input("Enter < > or =: ")
     population = input("Enter population: ")
     pop = display.get_pop(op, population)
     for p in pop:  
     print(pop)
```

I am getting the following error.

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064,......

Please help thanks

Comment: You can't do this. You can't parameterize the operator, you'll need to `.format()` (or similar) that in to the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking that `op` indeed contains either "<>" or "=" and that `pop` indeed contains a number you could try:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE Population " + op + " %s";
```

Beware of SQL injection.

Then

```
cursor.execute(query, (pop))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help J.R.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this. Parameterization works for values only, not operators or table names, or column names. You'll need to format the operator into the string. Do *not* confuse the `%s` placeholder here with Python string formatting; MySQL is awkward in that it uses %s for binding parameters, which clashes with regular Python string formatting.

The MySQL `%s` in a query string escapes the user input to protect against SQL Injection. In this case, I set up a basic test to see if the operation part submitted by the user was in a list of accepted operations.

```
def get_pop(op, pop):
    query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE Population {} %s" # Add a placeholder for format

    with conn: # Where does this come from?
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        if op in ['=', '!=']:
            cursor.execute(query.format(op), (pop,))
            x = cursor.fetchall()
            return x
```

You'll want to come up with some reasonable `return` value in the case that `if op in ['=', '!=']` is not `True` but that depends entirely on how you want this to behave.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)